# Javascript: загрузка изображений с images.google.com

Tags: javascript, парсер, google-images

подскажите пожалуйста как вывести к примеру 4 изображения на экран, вот оригинал:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Подключение jQuery
google.load('jquery', '1.4.2');
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
var image_key=encodeURIComponent('Купить слона');
function getimage(id) {
    $('#img1')['attr']('src', 'http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/26.gif');
    $['getJSON']('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=' + image_key + '&rsz=2&imgsz=medium&callback=?', function (json) {
        $('#img1')['attr']('src', (json['responseData']['results'][id]['url']));
        $('#img1')['error'](function () {
            getimage(id + 1);
        });
    });
};
getimage(0);
});
  </script>


  <img id="img1" width="100" alt="[KEY]" title="[KEY]">

  <br />
```

Вот моя попытка (просьба ногами не бить):

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Подключение jQuery
google.load('jquery', '1.4.2');
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
var image_key=encodeURIComponent('Купить слона');
for (j=1; j<=4; j++) function getimage(id) {
    
    $('#img' + j)['attr']('src', 'http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/26.gif');
    $['getJSON']('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=' + image_key + '&rsz=4&imgsz=medium&callback=?', function (json) {
        $('#img' + j )['attr']('src', (json['responseData']['results'][id]['url']));
        $('#img' + j )['error'](function () {
            getimage(id + 2);
        });
    });
};

getimage(0);

});

  </script>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i<4; $i++)
{
  echo '<img id="img'.$i.'" width="100" alt="[KEY]" title="[KEY]">';
}
?>
```

Вот

Comment: оригинал чего ? что вывести ? по-древнее то версию jQuery не могли найти ?

Comment: [так что-ли ?](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/x58Rq/)

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но можно с помощью яваскрипта получать только ссылки на изображения а на HTML выводить их так (к примеру по 4 картинки):
<img id="img1" src="ССЫЛКА ДО ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ_1.jpg" title="" alt="" />
<img id="img2" src="ССЫЛКА ДО ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ_2.jpg" title="" alt="" />
<img id="img3" src="ССЫЛКА ДО ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ_3.jpg" title="" alt="" />
<img id="img4" src="ССЫЛКА ДО ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ_4.jpg" title="" alt="" />

Comment: @eicto, по пристойнее картинок найти не могли !?

Comment: @srazil  - а вы и получаете src, посмотрите в консоле на объект results, там все есть.

@Francesco с каких это пор такие картинки не адекватны ? http://youtu.be/T-TA57L0kuc

Comment: Может я не понимаю, попробую подробнее объяснить - возможно ли получать ссылки на изображения яваскриптом и далее передать их PHP-переменную?

Comment: @srzil через ajax только, да и вопрос - зачем ?

Comment: а есть вариант получить с гугла картинки не нагружая хостинг?